# Function with templates as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

How do I pass function that has template argument to other function?

```
template <class _T>
void inc(int &x) {
    x++;
}

template <class FUNC>
void add(int &x, FUNC f) {
    f(x);
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    add(x, inc);
    return 0;
}
```

So, I get "error: no matching function for call to 'add'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inc` is a template, not a function. You need to pass `inc<int>`:

```
template <class _T>
void inc(int &x) {
    x++;
}

template <class FUNC>
void add(int &x, FUNC f) {
    f(x);
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    add(x, inc<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

(Fixed the typo calling `f` in the main function instead of add.)

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to pass the template arguments to the templated functions:

```
template <class _T>
void inc(int &x) {
    x++;
}

template <class FUNC>
void add(int &x, FUNC f) {
    f(x);
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    add(x, inc<int>); // <-- here
    return 0;
}
```